# What is the process of creating multiple document inside single array using node and mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

This is node js code and I am using it to insert multiple JSON documents inside a single array. I am inserting values in MongoDB using this node js code and using this schema. I have inserted the document properly but every time I have inserted it will create a new document of all values.
Is this possible that every time i inserted questionId score and time it will store inside of quiz array? Else creating a new document of quiz
array in mongodb.
for example  `[{"0":questionId:1,"score":1,"time":1-Sep-2016},{"1":questionId:2,"score":0,"time":1-Sep-2016}` ....etc] inside quiz array.

1). This node js code that I am using

```
    try {

    var quizArr = [];
    var quizObj = {
        'questionId': req.params.questionId,
        'score': req.params.score,
        'time': new Date().toISOString()

    };
    quizArr.push(quizObj);
    var userObj = {
        'userId':req.params.userId,
        'quiz':quizArr
    };


    var childinfoSave = new quizChild(userObj);

    childinfoSave.save(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }else{
          //res.send("Child questionId score and date saved successfully" + data);
          res.send(data);
          console.log("Child questionId score and date saved successfully");
        }
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error While Saving the child questionId score and Date ' + err);
    return next(err);
  }
```

2). And I am using this Schema

```
    2). Schema


  quiz: {type: Array,
   questionId: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Question',
          index: true
          },
  score: { type: Number },
  time: { type: String }
  }
```

3). This is the stored result inside MONGODB

```
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("57c1549926bbb3891a90db1a"),
    "quiz" : [
     {
        "questionId" : ObjectId("57c14a36b78cd543fc59b827"),
        "score" : 1,
        "time" : "2016-08-27T08:51:37.503Z",
        "_id" : ObjectId("57c1549926bbb3891a90db1b")
    }
  ],
  "__v" : 0
  }
  {
  "_id" : ObjectId("57c154a626bbb3891a90db1c"),
  "quiz" : [
     {
        "questionId" : ObjectId("57c14a36b78cd543fc59b828"),
        "score" : 1,
        "time" : "2016-08-27T08:51:50.898Z",
        "_id" : ObjectId("57c154a626bbb3891a90db1d")
     }
 ],
 "__v" : 0
 }
```

4) Instead of above two document, I want to create a single document inside a single array of the quiz with multiple Object.

```
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("57c1549926bbb3891a90db1a"),
   "quiz" : [
       {
          "questionId" : ObjectId("57c14a36b78cd543fc59b827"),
          "score" : 1,
          "time" : "2016-08-27T08:51:37.503Z",
          "_id" : ObjectId("57c1549926bbb3891a90db1b")
        },
      {
        "questionId" : ObjectId("57c14a36b78cd543fc59b828"),
        "score" : 1,
        "time" : "2016-08-27T08:51:50.898Z",
        "_id" : ObjectId("57c154a626bbb3891a90db1d")
    }
    ],
  "__v" : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have inserted the first record, you need to update it the next time when you are getting the request.

```
db.collName.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("57c1549926bbb3891a90db1a")},
                    {$push:{quiz : quizObj}});
```

Or

```
 db.collName.update({ "userId" : ObjectId(req.params.userId.toString())},
                    {$push:{quiz : quizObj}});
```

See [update-mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) more information about how to update.